# How to encrypt a database coloumn in visual studio 2010 c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010

Hi Guys i have a  oracle database connected to my website which i have created in visual studio 2010 using c# language. I have a table which has users passwords saved in the table.

When I input the password into the table it can be seen (which I do not want). I want it to be encrypted to ensure that password cannot be seen once entered into the database. Any help would be grateful.
 My user table looks like this:

```
Create TABLE users (
  user_id number(5) NOT NULL , 
  user_username VARCHAR(30), 
  user_password VARCHAR(20), 
  user_email VARCHAR(75), 
  user_street VARCHAR(50), 
  user_city VARCHAR(50), 
  user_state VARCHAR(2), 
  user_postcode VARCHAR(20), 
  user_phone VARCHAR(50),  
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id) 
) ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Encryption is done BEFORE it goes into your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and usual way to store password is, store a *hash* of the *password*
like below:-

```
HASHBYTES('SHA1', convert(VARCHAR(20), @user_password)
```

By adding `hash` you can check whether the password matches or not.

**NOTE:-** Here you might also not be knowing what is the actual password stored in the database column. So even if the hacker, hacks your complete database he still won't be able to know the password.

Also, you may search on the web for some more secure and encrypted things related to security.

Here are some more links:-

[Querying encrypted values in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081516/querying-encrypted-values-in-database)

[Best way to store password in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

[Encrpyt and Decrypt the username and password](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Username-or-Password-stored-in-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Hope this much help to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply do i put this code into the  sql database or into visual studio somewhere?

Comment: The above code has to be added in the visual studio on button click when you will be saving the data. Also u need to create a column in sql table where the encrypted password will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hashing technique,

public class Security
{
    public static string HashSHA1(string value)
    {
        var sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
        var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

}

in visual studio ,
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Security.HashSHA1(password));

// will be stored as,

### UserId | Username        | Password

1      | AlluvialDeposit | mySecretPassword

2      | AlluvialDeposit | F032680299B077AFB95093DE4082F625502B8251